# Expectation of a Function of Stationary Process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

Let $X \left( s\right)$ be a stationary process with finite second moment and $E \left( X \left( s \right) \right) = 0$. Suppose
$$Z \left( s \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 1 + \frac{X \left( s\right) X \left( s+h \right)}{\left| X \left( s\right) X \left( s+h \right)\right|} \right].$$

Show that
$$E \left( Z \left( s \right) \right) = \frac{1}{\pi}cos^{-1} \left( -R_X \left( h \right) \right)$$

where $R_X \left( h \right)$ is the correlation function of $X \left( s \right)$.

This is **not** homework. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Which book or forum? Can you please give the link?

Comment: It was on a past exam. Not even sure if it is correct. I tried some special cases and it was correct.